# Get the first 4 digits of each element of an array

Tags: php, arrays, substr

I have an array which i got from an sql database, and each element is saved as
YYYY-MM-DD. but i only need the year of each element.  My current code:

```
if(isset($_GET['date'])){
$dates= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['date']));
foreach($dates as $i){
$year = substr($i, 0, 4);
}}
print_r($year);
```

but when i run the code it only gives me the year of the first element

i already tried array_slice but that didnt work either

Comment: You will only get the last value as you are overriding that `$year` variable...Can you tell us how you want to use those year values?

Comment: As an aside note also, I would mention that `i`, as a variable, in pretty much all languages, is traditionally reserved (by style convention, not explicitly) for iteration and integers, not for values. It probably reads better if you use something like `foreach($dates as $date)` or `foreach($dates as $s)` (for 'string') rather than potentially confusing a situation in which `$i` IS acutally an integer (such as, commonly, when $i represents a packed or epoch form such as a unix timestamp).

Comment: Very well, i will keep that in mind my friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $dates= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['date']));
    $year = array();
    foreach($dates as $i) {
        $year[] = substr($i, 0, 4);
    }
}
print_r($year);
```

2 little changes that will fix it.

Comment: Thank god, i've been at this for a few hours now trying to figure it out!
Dankjewel barmhartige samaritaan

Answer (score 1):

cause your `$year` is a variable so value of `$year` will be overwrite on each iteration try to define `$year` as an `array()` so every time value will be added on new array index

```
$year[] = substr($i, 0, 4);
```

Comment: i can't see as an array

Comment: @RakeshSharma because people don't know the difference between $year and $year[] s/

Comment: Your answer was correct but your explanation was poor. People vote quickly here !

Comment: @Debflav may be trying to add more explanation

Comment: @RakeshSharma I likewise downvoted, not because you were wrong, but simply because you didn't actually explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like each date's year, you should use them as you extract them. For example, you could put them in an array:

```
$years = array();
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $dates= unserialize(urldecode($_GET['date']));
    foreach($dates as $i){
        $year = (int)substr($i, 0, 4);
        if (($year >= 1900) && ($year <= 2050))
            $years[] = $year;
    }
}
print_r($years);
```

Notice that you can also test the validity of your dates before appending the the array `$years`. You can, of course, also test the resulting array itself. You can also use them "on-the-fly" inside the foreach loop if you choose.

However, you cannot reassign the same variable a different value and expect it to be anything other than the last value assigned to it.